# Density Plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, data-visualization

I am trying to make interactive density plots for my data in R. I am able to make a basic density plot for some simulated data:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

a = rnorm(100,10,10)
b = plot(density(a))

b
```

[image]

Now, I am trying to make this an interactive plot. I tried the following line of code, but I get an empty plot:

```
ggplotly(b)
```

Therefore, I tried to replicate the original density plot "b" using the "ggplot2" library:

```
p <- ggplot(a, aes(x=a)) + 
    geom_density()

ggplotly(p)
```

This seems to work:

[image]

But at the same time I get an error:

```
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector
```

Can someone please explain why this error comes?

Thanks

Comment: that's one of the clearest error messages you will come by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
a <- data.frame(a)
p <- ggplot(a, aes(x=a)) + 
     geom_density()
ggplotly(p)
```

**Reasons for your error messages**

**1.**
The reason `ggplotly(b)` gives an error is that you need to give a ggplot object to `ggplotly`.

**2.**

```
a = rnorm(100,10,10) 
p <- ggplot(a, aes(x=a)) +  # does not work
    geom_density()
```

The reason you have an error for this because `a` is not a data.frame, it is a matrix.